# Return Exact results from LINQ Contains

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have table contains XYZ column example. Below in the Sample Data.

```
XYZ
-------
Sales,
Sales_units,
Sales_Units_Per,
ATL
```

I have to write a Linq query to pass some input values and get the results, so i am using below Code for the same.

```
string check="Sales_units,ATL";
var res = objlist.where(x=> check.Contains(x.XYZ)).ToList();
```

This is returning following values:

```
Sales,
Sales_units,
ATL
```

But My result should be like : `Sales_units, ATL`

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi mani654, It would be great if you create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with input and what will be expected value. We are not sure what are the values present in `objlist`, what value stores in `XYZ` property

Comment: Hi Thanks for the replay, XYZ Column is Having 4 values like Sales,Sales_units, Sales_Units_Per and ATL. If i Use Contains with Sales_units, ATL, its is returning Sales,Sales_units, ATL. So I want The result Only Sales_units, ATL.

Comment: Objlist is List of strings . string[] objlist = ["Sales","Sales_Units","Sales_Units_per","ATL"] . I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

try this ->   `var check = new string[] { "Sales_units", "ATL" };`

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that the word `"Sales_units"` actually contains `"Sales"`.
It looks like your data would allow to split the string first along the `,` marks and then see if substrings are equal rather than if they contain something.

An alternative could be a regex to find start or comma followed by the word followed by end or comma with some whitespace in between.

I took the liberty of writing out a string split version.
I will leave the regex version up to you.

```
class Program
{

    class Ws {
        public string XYZ;
        public Ws(string xyz) { XYZ = xyz; } }

    static void ConsoleWrite(string name, IEnumerable<Ws> list) {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        foreach (var item in list)
            Console.WriteLine($"  '{item.XYZ}'"); }

    static IEnumerable<Ws> Original(IEnumerable<Ws> objlist) {
        string check = "Sales_units,ATL";
        var res = objlist.Where(x => check.Contains(x.XYZ)).ToList();
        return res; }

    static IEnumerable<Ws> StringSplitVersion(IEnumerable<Ws> objlist) {
        string[] checks = "Sales_units,ATL".Split(',');
        return objlist.Where(x => checks.Any(c => c.Equals(x.XYZ))); }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var objlist = new List<Ws> { new Ws("Sales"), new Ws("Sales_units"), new Ws("Sales_Units_Per"), new Ws("ATL") };
        ConsoleWrite("original", Original(objlist));
        ConsoleWrite("stringsplit", StringSplitVersion(objlist)); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try join statement in LINQ. Check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) for more insight.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string check = "Sales_units,ATL";
        var checkList = check.Split(",");

        var objlist = new List<Columns>();

        var result = objlist.Join(checkList, c => c.XYZ, s => s, (c, s) => c);

    }

    class Columns
    {
        public string XYZ { get; set; }
    }
```